# unable to redirect after json post

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, modal-dialog

I have the following jquery code in my view

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            width: '500px'
        });

        $(".deleteLink").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var targetUrl = $(this).attr("href");
            var dID = $(this).attr("id");
            $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
                buttons: {
                    "Confirm": function () {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: '@Url.Action("DeleteSession")',
                            type: 'POST',
                            data: { id: dID },
                            success: function (data) {
                                    window.location.herf = data.redirectToUrl;
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    "Cancel": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });

            $("#dialog-confirm").dialog("open");
        });
    });
</script>
```

This link that triggers the dialog box is;

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "", new { id = s.ID },new { @class = "deleteLink", id = s.ID})
```

The controller method `DeleteSession` returns a `Json` result.

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult DeleteSession(int id)
{

    try
    {
        sRep.DeleteSession(id);
        return Json(new {success = true, redirectToUrl = Url.Action("Index")});
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return Json(new {success = false, redirectToUrl = Url.Action("DisplayError", new { eerror = 
                                    "Unable to delete the course. " + "Internal error: " + e.Message})});
    }

}
```

I have inspected the `Json` result and it seems fine. The only problem is `window.location.herf = data.redirectToUrl;` its not working. The page is not redirected and the dialog box is still on the screen.

any idea what i am doing wrong?

Comment: lol that wasn't the only typo I made ... I clearly need to step away from the computer for a bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you meant to do  `window.location.href`

Your original code:

```
window.location.herf = data.redirectToUrl;
```

Should be changed to:

```
window.location.href = data.redirectToUrl;
```

Comment: Unfortunately that can commonly be the case when you have been working on a piece of code for a long time. That is why it is good to take a break every once and a while. It is easier to find little bugs when you are looking at some code for the first time or after a little break.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use

```
$(window.location).attr('href',data.redirectToUrl);
```

Comment: Any benefits doint it this way? Why would you want to use jquery wrapper, when the native js is shorter and more clear?

Comment: @serrghi its more of cross browser support issues... and also, am a great fan of jquery... I guess its all abt personal preference